# Add conditions to expand grid in R?

Tags: r, combinations

Is there anyway to incorporate conditions/restrictions into `expand.grid` in R?

As an example, how would I prevent the combination `c(1,1,1)` and `c(2,2,2)` from appearing while the grid is being created? Is there a scalable solution that would work with many restrictions? My grid is large and my memory cannot handle it, e.g `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 32.0 Gb`, so subsetting after the grid is created is not an option.

```
expand.grid(A = rep(1:2),
            B = rep(1:3),
            C = rep(1:4))
```

Code below does not work:

```
expand.grid(A[!((A==1 & B==1 & C==1) & (A==2 & B==2 & C==2))] = rep(1:2),
            B[!((A==1 & B==1 & C==1) & (A==2 & B==2 & C==2))] = rep(1:3),
            C[!((A==1 & B==1 & C==1) & (A==2 & B==2 & C==2))] = rep(1:4))

as.data.frame(expand.grid(A = rep(1:2),
                          B = rep(1:3),
                          C = rep(1:4)))[!((A==1 & B==1 & C==1) & (A==2 & B==2 & C==2))]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you showed wouldn't work because `A`, `B`, `C` are not yet created

Answer (score 1):

If we create the dataset

```
d1 <-  expand.grid(A = rep(1:2),
        B = rep(1:3),
        C = rep(1:4))
```

Can use `rowSums` to check if the data is equal to the first column

```
d1[!!rowSums(d1 != d1[,1]),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign the `expand.grid` data frame and then run needed logic which you can shorten by comparing equality across all columns (`A==C` not needed per the transitive property of equality):

```
d1 <-  expand.grid(A = rep(1:2),
                   B = rep(1:3),
                   C = rep(1:4))

d1 <-  with(d1, d1[!(A==B & B==C),])
```